# Is creating a function to do a small repeated task an anti-pattern?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, design-patterns, anti-patterns

I am trying to learn best practices for programming and want to keep my code as clean as possible, but also maintainable. For example, I am running a program that waits for each element to be created.

```
a.waitForElementToAppear(50000);
b.waitForElementToAppear(50000);
c.waitForElementToAppear(50000);
```

Now, I added a function so I can easily change the `50000` without having to manually edit each one:

```
function waitForElement(element) {
    element.waitForElementToAppear(5000);
}
```

and have changed the above code to:

```
waitForElement(a);
waitForElement(b);
waitForElement(c);
```

Is it an anti-pattern to create a new function to call for a relatively small task? Is there a better approach?

Answer (score 6):

> Is it an anti-pattern to create a new function to call for a relatively small task?

No, it is absolutely fine! Although you're right that your function is so small that it hardly gains anything.

> Is there a better approach?

To achieve your goal of easily changing the shared argument value, you could *alternatively* (not necessarily "better") also put it in a variable:

```
const time = 50000;
a.waitForElementToAppear(time);
b.waitForElementToAppear(time);
c.waitForElementToAppear(time);
```

Last but not least, that code still is a bit repetitive. Another option would be a loop (although those three items are just about the threshold for a loop being sensible):

```
for (const element of [a, b, c]) {
    element.waitForElementToAppear(5000);
}
```

Comment: You could also have a default value for `waitForElementToAppear` so you don't have to pass in the time in all cases.

Comment: To add to @Jacob, you declare a default value for an argument with `function myFunction(time = 5000)` with the equals sign

Comment: Could you not do `waitForElements([a, b, c], 50000)`?  Or with the default added `waitForElements([a, b, c])`.

Comment: @Paul That's exactly the same as my last snippet, except you put it inside a function.